# Libre Office Calc causes problems in recovering Excel-Files

Tags: libreoffice

Installation:Lubuntu 14.04 LTS alongside WIN-XP **Problem:** If I work/edit an MS-Excel-File with Libre Office during the Lubuntu-Session and save this with the same file name and at its original location, then I have noticed, that this file does not open in WIN-XP. Only Excel opens, not the file? To cure this, I selected System-Restore to a date in the past and prior to the date of editing the Excel-file  >all OK!(but no more working the Excel-Fie with Libre Office)                                          QUESTION: Does anyone know why this happens or what does setting Libre Office changes?     Ricky

Answer (score 0):

I have opened and re-saved a number of excel files originally created under XP without a problem.

When saving your LibreOffice Calc file (to open again under MS Office Excel) are you making sure that you have saved the file in the correct format?

In the Save As dialogue box, you can select the file type from a drop down list. You may just need to check that it is the correct type for the version of Excel you are using.

Comment: Ok, the files were saved to their origins, therefore also .xls; but I did not make a prior check. But not only the file in question, the problem occured with all and any other Excel-File, also those that were not touched i.e. a general conflict!    Will try out at some later instance, as I do not wish to have to reset my system back again presently. Ricky